# Making oEmbed work on the excerpt field

Tags: excerpt, oembed

How can I make oEmbed work on the excerpt field so I only have to paste the youtube url in there and then be able to echo 'get_the_excerpt()'?

I also want to filter oEmbed and change the wmode but I think I found a solution for that here:
http://code.hyperspatial.com/all-code/wordpress-code/oembed-wmode/

EDIT: Crap! I was wrong, it doesn't work at all, nothing happens. Anyone got a better solution?

Comment: I assume the answer from Rarst below now works for you? Then you could maybe edit this question to remove the addition that it does not work? It's a bit confusing now :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely sure it is supposed to be used like this, but by analogue with `the_content` try this:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', array($wp_embed, 'autoembed'), 9);
```

Comment: Sorry Rarst, it doesn't seem to work! I had forgotten to remove some code so it looked like it was working but it didn't.

Comment: @Richard B it works on my test stack for couple URLs I tried. Do you get any errors? Try with `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in `wp-config.pnp`. Also if you are running code inside function don't forget to declare `global $wp_embed;`

Comment: I'm getting a lot of errors but none that are specific for this matter. Echoing get_the_excerpt only prints the youtube url in pure text...

Comment: @Richard B ah, if you use `get_the_excerpt()` directly this filter is never applied. Use `the_excerpt()` or move change `the_excerpt` to `get_the_excerpt` in `add_filter()`. PS and you should probably work on those "lot of errors" if possible. :) Never good thing...

Comment: Ah ok, I got it to work now using only the_excerpt on my test site, of course. Maybe I can change to that everywhere but it would be nice to be able to use get_the_excerpt as well. Think thats possible?

Comment: It's working on my live site now! Thanks again! :)

Comment: If not using the_excerpt() but get_the_excerpt(), you should apply the filter on 'get_the_excerpt' hook.